# nodejs + SSL + Nginx: how to make them run together, where are privkey.pem and cert.pom located?

Tags: node.js, ssl, nginx

on my apache server, I used that to allow nodejs to use ssl

```
var ssl = {
    key:  fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/privkey.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/cert.pem')
};
```

My client switched his http server to Nginx ruled by PLESK

I tried with:

```
var ssl = {
    key:  fs.readFileSync('/usr/local/psa/var/certificates/cert-lcQuQ3'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/usr/local/psa/var/certificates/cert-RVySSD')
};
```

and not good: Infact I have no idea where are the equivalent to privkey.pem and cert.pem with nginx

Any idea .

Comment: If you are using lets encrypt, despite the change the certs should be in the same place...

Comment: No: my client used PLESK